# Kubernetes Service Deployment

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes

I have recently started exploring kuberenetes and done with practical implementation of pods,services and replication Controller on google cloud. I have some doubts over service and network access .
First, Where is the service deployed which will work as load balancer for group of pods ?
Second, does the request to access an application running in pod using a service load balancer go through master or direct to minions nodes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service proxy runs on each node on the cluster. From inside the cluster, when you make a request to a service IP, it is intercepted by the service proxy and routed to a pod matching the label selector for the service. If you have specified an external load balancer for your service, the load balancer will pick a node to send the request to, at which point it will be captured by the proxy and directed to an appropriate pod. If you are using public IPs, then your router will send the request to the node with the public IP where it will be captured by the proxy and directed to an appropriate pod.

If you followed by description, you can see that service requests do not go through the master. They bounce through a proxy running on the nodes.

As an aside, there is also a proxy running on the master, which you can use to reach nodes, services, pods, but this proxy isn't in the packet path for services that you create within the cluster.

Comment: Thanks now where will this external load balancer reside ?

Comment: As the name implies, it's external to the Kubernetes cluster. If you create on on GCE or AWS, for instance, we configure the cloud networking load balancer for the cloud platform.

Comment: what if i am creating Kubernetes cluster locally in virtual box ? now where this service be running

Comment: Take a look at the third paragraph of https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/services.md#external-services and see if that helps.